# Test ideas for a real-time comment system

Tags: manual-testing, testcase, test-creation

I am testing functionality that allows different users to exchange comments in real-time i.e. every user receives updates on all the events (comment added, comment deleted, total number of comments updated etc) without refreshing the page - something similar to FB comments posting.

I am looking for some fresh ideas for test scenarios. 
I checked basic scenarios of posting/deleting comments.
I checked scenario when one user deletes comments and one user adds comments
I checked connectivity issues (to see what happens when a user loses and restores his connection).

I am a bit new to testing this kind of systems, so I will really appreciate if you guys could help me out with some ideas?

Comment: This is not really a good place to ask such questions. The Stack Exchange  format does not fit well for discussion. Typically it is best to ask questions that have a singular or not too many answers.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. I guess you are right, but I m struggling to find an information that could help me to come up with some new test scenarios for the real-time system. I am relatively new at testing.. By asking this question I wasn't expecting somebody to give me a complete list of scenarios. I was just hoping that some people, obviously more experienced than me, could share some ideas about possible cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider:

- test low bandwidth as well as none.  Chrome has an option to emulate slower connections.
- testing posting empty comments and large comments.
- test posting comments with special characters including letters with inflections
- test posting comments as a sql injection attack
- check if a comment can be posted twice or if it considered a dupe
- test on different devices.  Use emulators and services for different devices and browsers.
- test being logged in with two browsers at the same time
- test 4 or 5 posts being done withon one second
- test posting 2000 message by User A while User B is offline then User B goes online

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply! You helped me a lot! I really appreciate it!